# Is it possible to create a multi node spark cluster using one mac and one ubuntu machine?

Tags: apache-spark, distributed-computing

I have a mac and a dell laptop running Ubuntu. Is it possible to create a spark cluster using these two machines running different operating systems?

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a try and was able to create a two node spark cluster using a mac running macOS and a dell laptop running ubuntu desktop. I had to ensure that paths for Java,Spark,Scala are matching on both machines and permissions on spark directory.

[image]

Comment: It's not recommended to do this, however, unless you are managing both systems using Puppet, Ansible for example

Comment: I am quite new to this and wanted to do this setup for learning spark (as their are differences when spark run on multinode cluster). When you say it is not suggested then is it because of different operating systems or in general?

Comment: There should not be differences. The JVM would run the same code. Anything else comes down to the kernel and the OS packages. In any company, their Spark cluster is almost always all the same OS because they use configuraiton management software